# opening pdf stream in new window using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, struts2, dojo

I am using `struts2` framework and `dojo` for ui. I want to display a pdf in new browser window. I am getting pdf inputstream from server via normal ajax call get method(didnt use dojo ajax call. used native js ajax call ).
How to view pdf string in a new browser window?

### js code:

/*two inputs to get pdf file*/

```
 var selectedFileSlot={"END407":"report_28_03_13.pdf","END408":"[B@cef121c","END409":"*.pdf;*.doc;*.docx;*.odt;*.ods","END410":"5242880"}
        var selectedNode=   {"objectID":"22df1b2601a3552f24e5f011abc27f86","specID":"2001","entityConcreteID":"11000"}


    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  {
          alert(xmlhttp.response);
          window.open(xmlhttp.response);//not able to open in new browser window
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","downloadDocument.action?selectedNode=" + JSON.stringify(selectedNode) + "&selectedFileSlot=" + JSON.stringify(selectedFileSlot),true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

### struts.xml code:

```
<action name="downloadDocument" class="commonAction" method="downloadDocument">
    <interceptor-ref name="sessionStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="cachingStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success" type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
    <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${fileFileName}"</param>
    <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
    </action>
```

### action class code:

```
commonDTO.setSelectedNode(this.selectedNode);
commonDTO.setSelectedFileSlot(this.selectedFileSlot);
byte[] bytes = commonDAO.getDownloadDocument(commonDTO); //getting pdf as byte array
inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the binary content of the PDF file, that you can't handle in Javascript, and that you need to return with `application/pdf` Content-type (not `text/html` or `application/octet-stream`), with a [Stream result](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/stream-result.html).

Why on earth are you using AJAX to load it **in a new window** ? Just use [one of the following way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16900840/1654265).